# The method create() is undefined fir the type Problem

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

So I am trying to build a simple RESTful Api using Java and Spring framework. I am following the spring docs for this at [https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/](https://stackoverflow.com). However, I have ran into an issue where the method "create()" is not defined for type "Problem". This part of the tutorial does not show how to import "Problem" or where the method "created()" comes from. It's possible the import used for "Problem" is incorrect.

Here is the code snippet where it is used in a DeleteMapping and PutMapping. I've looked everywhere and nothing useful comes up on how to fix this or what import to use. Thank you.

```
//Current import for Problem
import org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.Problem;
```

```
@DeleteMapping("/orders/{id}/cancel")
ResponseEntity<?> cancel(@PathVariable Long id) {

  Order order = orderRepository.findById(id) //
      .orElseThrow(() -> new OrderNotFoundException(id));

  if (order.getStatus() == Status.IN_PROGRESS) {
    order.setStatus(Status.CANCELLED);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(assembler.toModel(orderRepository.save(order)));
  }

  return ResponseEntity //
      .status(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED) //
      .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaTypes.HTTP_PROBLEM_DETAILS_JSON_VALUE) //
      .body(Problem.create() //
          .withTitle("Method not allowed") //
          .withDetail("You can't cancel an order that is in the " + order.getStatus() + " status"));
}
```

```
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}/complete")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable Long id) {

  Order order = orderRepository.findById(id) //
      .orElseThrow(() -> new OrderNotFoundException(id));

  if (order.getStatus() == Status.IN_PROGRESS) {
    order.setStatus(Status.COMPLETED);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(assembler.toModel(orderRepository.save(order)));
  }

  return ResponseEntity //
      .status(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED) //
      .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaTypes.HTTP_PROBLEM_DETAILS_JSON_VALUE) //
      .body(Problem.create() //
          .withTitle("Method not allowed") //
          .withDetail("You can't complete an order that is in the " + order.getStatus() + " status"));
}
```

Comment: Check if the version of spring boot used in the tutorial matches the one you're using, most likely it does not. 
I see the tutorial is using spring boot 2.3.0, that's ancient in web dev world.
I suggest you find a spring boot 2.7+ or better a spring boot 3 tutorial.
When learning how to use libraries it's important to learn how to use the latest (or if you need to, then learn a specific version), things change over time.

Comment: Thank you for the response and advice. Definitely will make sure versions are up to date the next time I do something like this.

Comment: I don't know where class `Problem` in that tutorial is supposed to come from, but the one you're using is not the right one. If you are using Spring Framework 6 / Spring Boot 3, you should use [`ProblemDetail`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ProblemDetail.html) instead. Note: It does not have a `create()` method, you'll have to create it in a different way, see the API documentation.

Comment: This is a better version of the tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/